# This form validation is not working in wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, plugins, onsubmit

This form validation code is not working in wordpress plugin, form directly gets submitted as if the `onsubmit` event is not there at all.
Please help

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:....
 * Description:.....
 * Version: Pre release
 * Author:....
 * Author URI:....
 **/
add_action("admin_menu", "create_menus");

function create_menus()
{
 add_menu_page("cash Details", "cash Details", 4, "form-page", "cash_deals_form_page");
}

function cash_deals_form_page()
{
?>
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["clientName"].value;
        if (x == "") {
            alert("Name must be filled out");
            return false;
        } else {
            return confirm('Do you really want to submit this entry?');
        }
    }
</script>
<div style='display:inline-block; width:48%;'>
    <form name="myForm" method='post' onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">
        Client Email (Type the Email Id of the client whom you want to allot cash):
        <br/>
        <input type='text' id='input1' name='clientName' maxlength='100'>
        <br/>
        <br/> Type the cash to be added in the client's account:
        <br/>
        <input type='number' id='input2' name='cash' min='-10000' max='100000000'>
        <br/>
        <br/> Type your comments here (optional):
        <br/>
        <textarea rows='4' cols='60' name='adminComment' maxlength='500'></textarea>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit'>
        <br/>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What did you expect? please clarify details. I think right now your code is ok.

Comment: @Ataur Rahman Munna I should have got an alert message after submitting with the first field blank, also if first field is filled out, I should have got a confirmation before form gets submitted.

Comment: @user7324674, that is the behavior [I get](http://jsbin.com/wenusodixu/edit?html,output)

Comment: @ Adam Azad  It's working fine independently, but it's actually part of a wordpress plugin, where except this part everything else is working fine.

Comment: @user7324674, could you link to the wordpress installation, if you have it, please?

Comment: @Adam Azad  I m using localhost

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it turned out that validateForm() is a predefined function in wordpress, just changing that name solved the problem!!!!!!